# How to align a menu to bottom of header

Tags: css, alignment

I'm trying to align a menu to the bottom of the `<nav>` where the menu `<ul>` is, but I can't do it.

I have tried using `vertical-align`, `text-align`, `bottom: 0`, `margin`s and `padding`s but I can't.

Here's an image of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Comment: Would be far better to get a code snippet on https://jsfiddle.net/ for instance. :)

Comment: Would you be willing to accept a JS/jQuery answer?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3k7mm4qg/

Comment: Im prefer resolve this with only css, html as simply as i can :D

Comment: @jaine Does my answer work? If not, then feedback please? If so, please accept?

Comment: it work by changing my code, and adding the JS, but im looking for do it with only CSS. Using top: 15 i can adapt the position to the bottom side, but i think there have to be another clear way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, used one line of JS:

```
$("#menu").css("top", $("#header").height() - $("#menu").height());
```

This absolutely-positions the menu's top.

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dckzjb21/).